# How to transfer a Rails project from a digital ocean droplet to a domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean

I have an Rails application deployed with capistrano on digital ocean droplet. The application is available on some server. (e.g. xxx.xx.xxx.xxx). I also have some domain (e.g. www.example.com)

So how can I transfer the application from xxx.xx.xxx.xxx to www.example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to your domain DNS manager and add a type A record that targets to your server IP address xxx.xx.xxx.xxx.

Assuming your domain registrar is GoDaddy, this [help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238) might help you.